# Ubuntu Server Crash

Tags: 18.04, crash

Hello 1 of my 2 servers keeps crashing randomly. the latest uptime of the machine was 17days but it then it suddenly crashes without any warning. This is the log from kern.log http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wzPhrF9r9g/ I could not see the screen because the computer completely locked up and i had to press the reset button for it to start responding. But the previous times it had crashed there was something about a CPU being stuck and that it had waited for 22s.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show logs at the end of the previous boot. `-b -2`, `-b 3`, etc. `journalctl --list-boots` shows what's available.

Comment: Are these bare metal machines or VMs? How does it crash? Is it just unresponsive or does it reboot? Could it be overheating? What was the load like? Was there enough available RAM?

Comment: @terdon can you and I meet in a chat session?

Comment: check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and then go to the manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS. Report back.

Comment: go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run the free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete. Report back.

Comment: I have updated to the latest available version for my mb (b350 tomahawk MSI) and i got a new problem with my internet connection, it doesnt recognise my intergrated lan adapter. But i dont know if the solution worked. and for some reason i cannot change my bios because for some reasion the new bios flash is broken for me and it says "null string" behind the usb. I will report back once it works.

Comment: Are you sure you flashed the correct BIOS for your machine? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Comment: With the new BIOS, did you select to restore the BIOS settings to factory default? You should. If so, you may have to check individual settings to assure that they're correct.